# Метод get экземпляра класса Workout не возвращает результата

Tags: php, ооп

Помогите найти ошибку или объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Суть проблемы: метод `get` экземпляра класса `Workout` ничего не возвращает, т.к. метод `getWorkoutId` не выполняется до конца.

```
class Workout
{
    private $userID;
    private $workoutID;
    private $day;
    private $link;
    private $workout = array();

    function __construct(mysqli $link, $userID, $day){
        $this->link = $link;
        $this->userID = $userID;
        $this->day = $day;
        $this->workoutID = $this->getWorkoutId();
    }

    private function getWorkoutId(){
        //echo "[link] = ".$this->link;
        //echo "[userID] = ".$this->userID;
        //echo "[day] = ".$this->day;

        $result = mysqli_query($this->link, "SELECT id FROM training WHERE user_id = '$this->userID' AND day = '$this->day' LIMIT 1") or die();
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        //echo "[row] = ".$row;
        echo "[WorkoutID] = ".$row['id'];

        return $row['id'];
    }

    function get(){
        return $this->workoutID;
    }
}

$mondayWorkout = new Workout($link, 1, "Mon");
echo $mondayWorkout->get();
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже выше написали - у тебя, скорее всего, ошибка в запросе, но она никак не проявляет себя.
Чтобы быть в курсе ошибок SQL, **их надо транслировать в ошибки РНР**. Но вот как именно это делать никто правильно написать не смог.

Во-первых, выше написана ерунда: на самом деле **НИКОГДА** нельзя писать `or die(что-нибудь)`. Причин этому много, об этом везде написано, я не буду повторяться. Если мы хотим получить ошибку, можно писать только `or trigger_error(что-нибудь)`.

Во-вторых, в случае с mysqli даже этого не нужно. Можно один раз установить нужную настройку и ошибки mysqli начнут сами транслироваться в ошибки PHP. *Перед* коннектом достаточно написать вот эту одну строчку

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

и больше не придется проверять вручную результат ни одной функции mysqli - очень удобно.

Что характерно - я уже не раз приводил здесь этот простой код, но мы же ведь тут все писатели, а не читатели, и поэтому никто ничему не учится. И продолжает давать советы двадцатилетней давности.

В общем, пишешь эту строчку перед коннектом и сразу видишь все ошибки запросов.

Далее.

Это не относится к твоей проблеме напрямую, но имеет **критическое значение для безопасности твоих скриптов:** ты не должен использовать mysqli как есть. Тебя заставляли сменить расширение mysql **не для того чтобы ты продолжал говнокодить в том же стиле,** просто добавив буковку i к именам функций. А для того, чтобы ты начал использовать **плейсхолдеры для подстановки значений в запрос**. Но у mysqli плейсхолдеры практически неюзабельны до такой степени, что средний пхпшник в принципе не в состоянии освоить работу с ними. Плюс - вообще никогда нельзя работать с сырым API, а надо всегда использовать более высокоуровневую надстройку. Таких настроек много, но встроенная в РНР только одна - PDO. Поэтому ты должен начать использовать PDO вместо mysqli. Этим ты сделаешь свои скрипты неуязвимыми для SQL инъекций и сократишь количество кода.

Вот твой метод, переписанный на PDO:

```
    private function getWorkoutId(){
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM training WHERE user_id = ? AND day = ?";
        $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array($this->userID, $this->day));
        return $stm->fetchColumn();
    }
```

тут все безопасно, и без лишнего кода.

Да. И если говорить об ошибках *ООП*, то класс Workout какой-то в целом бессмысленный. Класс, который состоит, по сути, из одного конструктора, должен быть методом, а не классом. Если это еще только заготовка, и методы будут дописываться - тогда ок. Но если это класс целиком, то я бы сделал его методом.

Comment: что-то не особо помогли ваши советы с 'mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);'

Comment: Спасибо. Только через год понял о чем вы мне тогда сказали, пока не столкнешся  с реальной практикой многого не поймешь.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте не просто or die, а с выводом сообщения.
Типа: 
`or die('opa!')` или `or die(mysqli_error($this->link))`. Тогда будет понятно где и почему остановка.

Вам надо проверить текст запроса с подставленными параметрами, например в phpmyadmin. Что-то в нем не так.